# Oracle doesn't see records in table

Tags: sql, oracle, select, insert

I have a table which contains some records. And I insert a new record if the same one isn't in the table. Usually it works correctly, but sometimes it doesn't see records in the table and the error "ORA-00001: unique constraint" raises.

I thought a commit was missed, but it haven't solved my problem. But I've found that if I delete records in the table and insert them again, it starts to work correctly. And next inserts work correctly too. But after some time, the error repeats again.

I don't do any other actions with the table.

```
FOR loading_data IN LoadingDataCursor
LOOP
  SELECT COUNT(1) INTO data_count FROM loaded_data l WHERE
  l.field1 = loading_data.field1 AND
  ...
  l.fieldN = loading_data.fieldN;

  IF data_count = 0 THEN
    INSERT INTO loaded_data ...;
  END IF;
END LOOP;

COMMIT;
```

Comment: This is difficult to debug as you didn't post test case (CREATE TABLE and INSERT INTO sample data) so we can't even *try* to run that code. Who knows what's going on? Maybe some other users are inserting rows (hence unique constraint was violated when you ran that code). Maybe some other users deleted rows and committed (hence you don't see rows). Maybe ...

Comment: If you have another sessions running where `COMMIT` is missing, your INSERT command should hang (and wait for the `COMMIT` or `ROLLBACK`) instead of raising ORA-00001

Comment: Your approach would be fine if there is only *one session* running this code. Apparently there are *several parallel sessions* running your code and therefore your logic with *test if exists* and *insert* is **absolutely unsuitable** as between your two steps other sessions can change the data. You must switch to a one statement implementation (`merge`)  or somehow *serialize* your connections. Additionally if you process lot of data you should try to get rid of the `loop`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Another transaction may commit a row between the time you do the `select` and the time you do the `insert`.  There may be unique constraints as well on subsets of columns.  If (`field1`, `field2`, `field3`) is unique, for example, you may try to insert a row which has has the same values for `field1`, `field2`, and `field3` as an existing row but a different `field4` value, your `select` won't find a row but your `insert` will get a unique constraint error.

Perhaps you want to do a `merge` where you `update` the row in `loaded_data` if there is a match on a key and `insert` the row if there is not

```
merge into loaded_data dest
  using( select loading_data.field1, loading_data.field2, ...
           from dual ) src
     on( src.field1 = dest.field1 and
         src.field2 = dest.field2 and 
         src.field3 = dest.field3 )
   when matched then update
     set dest.field4 = src.field4, 
         ...
   when not matched then insert( field1, field2, field3, ... fieldN )
     values( src.field1, src.field2, src.field3, ... src.fieldN );
```

Note that you can probably use the query you're using for the `loading_data` cursor in the `using` clause to just do the `merge` in a single operation.

You could try to do the `insert`, catch the exception, and do something (or nothing)

```
begin
  INSERT INTO loaded_data ...;
exception
  when dup_val_on_index 
  then
    null; -- Ignore the row if it violates a constraint
end;
```

You could use DML error logging to load all the rows that succeed and log all the rows that fail to load so that you can examine them

```
begin
  dbms_errlog.create_error_log( dml_table_name => 'loaded_data' );
end;

insert into loaded_data
  <<query from loading_data cursor>>
  log errors into err$_loaded_data 
    reject limit unlimited
```